# Set a default language using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing site which is multiple language supports.When initial page load it shows both languages,after that dropdown selection it shows selected language.

I wanted to Set Japanese is the Initial language.

```
                    <select onchange="select_language(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option value="en" >English</option>
                        <option value="jp" selected>Japanese</option>
                    </select>




<h3><span lang="en">Welcome</span><span lang="jp">Other Language</span></strong></h3>
```

Javascript

```
   function select_language(language) {
        $("[lang]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("lang") == language)
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @nmenego Initially it shows both languages.But i wanted to show only one language.(Html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css:

```
span[lang=en]{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    show_lang();
});
$("select").change(function () {
    show_lang();
});
function show_lang() {
    var language = $("select").val();
    $("[lang]").hide();
    $("[lang='"+language+"']").show();
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/R8S6v/3)

Comment: This does not address both languages being shown on initial page load, as the "change" does not happen until the user clicks another option from the drop down list.

Comment: In here initially NO Language Displays.I wanted to display Japanese Initially

Comment: Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8S6v/3/) again. It is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In the DOM ready function of jQuery, run logic similar to `select_language()` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedOptionValue = $('select option:selected').val();

    $("[lang]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("lang") == selectedOptionValue) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```